# How can I properly type a subclass of class which sub-types a Generic base class?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have two classes inheriting from `dict`, like this:

```
class A(dict):

class B(A):
```

This all works fine - the two classes use the inherited `dict` functionality and do other required stuff.  However, I also want to use type-hinting.  The first should reduce the range of the `Dict` generic and the second should reduce it further.  For example, I'd like to write something like:

```
class A(Dict[str, Any]):

class B(A[str, int]):
```

This works fine for `A` but not for `B` (that code is not syntactically correct, of course).

Class `B` isn't a sub-type of A (since it can't handle anything other than `int`) and that's fine but I do need it to inherit.  Can I get mypy to understand the correct type of `B` and still inherit from `A`?

The only solution I can see at present is to re-implement all the inherited methods from `A` but that would be a lot of runtime boiler-plate just to declare the correct typing.

Comment: you likely can't do that, B has to inherit from Dict directly because you are overriding the generic in the A's strucutre.

Comment: `B` is not a kind of `A` if `B`'s values have to be `int`s.

Comment: @chepner I don't want to claim that `B` is a subtype of `A` but I do want mypy to deduce the correct type for its inherited methods.

Comment: I'm saying that `B` should not inherit from `A`, because your claimed type is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. `lst: list[A] = [A(), B()]; for x in lst: x["foo"] = "bar"` You should not be able to assign `"bar"`to `x["foo"]` when `x` is the instance of `B`.

Comment: @chepner indeed. But I also don't want to re-write the methods of A in B, or have to explicitly delegate all of them to a B instance. The answer (as below) is to move that functionality out of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a little more thought and I think it's easy. I just need to move the shared functionality out of A and into a new generic which inherits from Dict.  Simple:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Dict, Any

KT = TypeVar('KT')
VT = TypeVar('VT')

class GenericA(Dict[KT, VT]):
    def my_method(self):
        print(list(self.values()))


A = GenericA[str, Any]

class B(GenericA[str, int]):
    def more_methods(self):
        print(list(self.keys()))

a = A({"a" : "blob", "b" : "blib"})
a.my_method()

b = B({"a" : 1, "b" : 2})
b.my_method()
b.more_methods()
```